Default value of wire is Z, but in first instantiation it is taking 0. How this is possible?
`include "fa.v"
 module FAn(a,b,s,c);
 parameter size=4;
 input [size-1:0]a;
 input [size-1:0]b;
 output reg [size-1:0]s;
 output c;
 wire [size:0] cin;
 genvar i;
 for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1)begin
 FA(.a(a[i]),.b(b[i]),.cin(cin[i]),.s(s[i]),.c(cin[i+1]));
 end
 assign c=cin[size];
 endmodule

Here in instantiation line:
FA(.a(a[i]),.b(b[i]),.cin(cin[i]),.s(s[i]),.c(cin[i+1])); 

in first iteration, I am passing cin[0] signal (cin(cin[0])).  Since I haven;t assigned any value to wire[size:0]cin, cin[0] default value should be "z" right, but it is taking zero (0) and passing that signal 0 to FA module in first instantiation.

Please show us how you determined that cin[0] was 0

There is a problem with your simulator.  cin[0] should be z instead of 0.  The simulation on EDA Playground demonstrates that it is z.
Another indication that there is a problem with your simulator is the following line:
FA(.a(a[i]),.b(b[i]),.cin(cin[i]),.s(s[i]),.c(cin[i+1]));

The line is missing the mandatory instance name after the module name (FA).  Your simulator should have given you a compile error.  This means that the simulator does not comply with the Verilog IEEE Std 1800.
One way to fix it is to add a name like dut:
FA dut (.a(a[i]),.b(b[i]),.cin(cin[i]),.s(s[i]),.c(cin[i+1]));

Any legal Verilog identifier can also be used.
You should see if there is a newer version of your simulator.  If so, you should upgrade to the newer version, or you should use a different simulator.

Here is the code I ran on EDA Playground:
module FA (input a,b,cin,output s,c);
endmodule

module FAn(a,b,s,c);
   parameter size=4;
   input        [size-1:0] a;
   input        [size-1:0] b;
   output reg   [size-1:0] s;
   output                c;
   wire [size:0]         cin;

   genvar i;
   for (i=0; i<size; i=i+1) begin
      FA dut (.a(a[i]),.b(b[i]),.cin(cin[i]),.s(s[i]),.c(cin[i+1]));
   end

   assign c = cin[size];
endmodule

module tb;
    parameter size=4;
    bit [size-1:0] a=3;
    bit [size-1:0] b=2;
    wire c;
    wire [size-1:0] s;

FAn dut (
    .a  (a),
    .b  (b),
    .c  (c),
    .s  (s)
);

   initial begin
      $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
      $dumpvars;
      #5 $finish;
   end
endmodule

